# jQuery Autosize plugin error - intermediate value(...) is not a function

Tags: jquery, autogrow

I use jQuery Autosize plugin:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

The script itself you can see here:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/js/jquery.autosize.js

This is how I use the script:

```
jQuery(function($){$(document).ready(function(){
$('textarea').autosize();
}
```

**Problem N 1**

Just updated the script to the latest version and it stopped to work:

```
"TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function"
```

Javascript console reports this error on the last line of the script:

```
}(window.jQuery || window.$));
```

**Problem N 2**

Script doesn't work in modal windows (PrettyPhoto) and javascript console doesn't show any errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's no reason to use `jQuery(function($){$(document).ready(...)})`. Passing a function into `jQuery` is the same as using `ready`. Just do `jQuery(function($) { ... });` without the call to `ready`.

Comment: A good practice when working with multiple JS files is to add a single semicolon at the very beginning of each file to terminate any preceding malformed logic.

Comment: For me it is happening when I define a function before IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

Answer (score 149):

the `"TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function"`
pops up as the result of missing a semi colon on the function BEFORE the one it throws an error on.  It might be as simple as:

```
jQuery(function($){$(document).ready(function(){
$('textarea').autosize();
}  
); //<-----
```

or it could be the function declared before that.
An example of how this is cause is in this code:

```
var populate = function(sw) {
  myglobalswitch = sw;
  window.setTimeout(repopulate, 250, sw);
}

(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
_create: function() {
....
})( jQuery );
```

results in the **Intermediate value is not...** on the last line: `})( jQuery );`

However, the fix is adding a semi colon to the populate function:

```
var populate = function(sw) {
  myglobalswitch = sw;
  window.setTimeout(repopulate, 250, sw);
}  ;
```

to prevent the parser from thinking that "var populate = ... " and (function($) ... are a single statement, the second extending from the first.

Comment: hint: any weird, inexplicable parsing errors are usually the result of misplaced quotes and semicolons

Comment: This also occurs if an IIFE is declared after an object, that does not end with a semicolon. This happens when 'option strict' is on.

Comment: While my code was in no way relevant to this, the semicolon FIXED EVERYTHING. Thank you! (Silly functions that return objects, in parenthesis to immediately call a function on said object). The next line's parenthesis were making the previous line parse as a function call

Answer (score 7):

FWIW the autosize invocation method has changed. If you end up here and are using it with jQuery

Previously it was

```
$('textarea').autosize();
```

The new invocation is

```
autosize($('textarea'));
```

Comment: Thanks, missed that completely!

Comment: Thanks for the note about version difference. Was trying to fix the error in old version.

Answer (score -1):

You may have declared a function, inside a function, after you needed it. This was my problem.